# Is it possible to get the element list in System.Web.Helpers.Json object

Tags: c#, json

I need to develop a generic tools in C# to display the content of a JSON object (which is a dynamic object of System.Web.Helpers.Json).

If I known the name of elements, I can use either json.name or json['name'] to retrieve the value of this element.  And it can also retrieve the data of json array.  So, if I have a list of element name, I can show the content inside.

But the problem is that I can't find any way to get such list.
If I view the object in debugger, it can shown the IDictionary object _values inside, and the elements are stored as Key-Value pairs.  So all the element name can be find as the Key in the array.  However, this is a private data inside the object, I cannot access it in the program.

May I know if there has any way to get the list of elements inside the System.Web.Helpers.Json object?

Comment: From [here](https://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/NuGet/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages/3.0.0-rc1/Release/Default/System.Web.Helpers/System.Web.Helpers/Json.cs?ImageName=System.Web.Helpers), `Json.Decode(string value)` would appear to return a [`DynamicJsonObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.dynamicjsonobject%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).  Try casting the return to that, and if not null, use [`GetDynamicMemberNames`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.dynamicjsonobject.getdynamicmembernames%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes, you are right.  GetDynamicMemberNames of DynamicJsonObject can return the list of element in the json object.  Thanks a lot.